# Full Width Prestashop CMS Page

Tags: css, content-management-system, prestashop

I'm using CMS Page for my content in Prestashop. I would like to have 100% full width background or content, especially for the image, to make it look like a landing page. 
However, there are still white space on left and right. Is there any solution for this?

[image: Full Width image content]

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't posted any example code, you could try setting the `background-size` property in the same element as your `background-image`.

Setting `background-size: cover` will make the image completely cover the area. `background-size: contain` will keep it proportional, and 100% width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In yourtemplate/header.tpl locate

```
<div class="columns-container">
    <div id="columns" class="container">
```

and change to

```
<div class="columns-container">
    <div id="columns" class="container{if $page_name =='cms'}-fluid{/if}">
```

This will cause that all CMS pages will have 100% width. Rest of the pages will be untouched.